# Omniauth Facebook - omniauth is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

Pulling my hair out on this : being redirected to user/sign_up - here is my code:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
             :confirmable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

      def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
          where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
            user.provider = auth.provider
            user.uid = auth.uid
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
            user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
        ##  user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
          end
      end

    end

    class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
      def facebook
        # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
        omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        @user ||= User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

         Rails.logger.level = 0 
          logger.debug "Session: #{@session.inspect}"
          logger.debug "USer: #{@user.inspect}"
          logger.debug "Omniauth: #{@omniauth.inspect}"

        if @user.persisted?
          sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
        else
          session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end

    end
```

And here is the relevant logger output:
 Session: nil

Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
 USer: #
 Omniauth: nil
 Redirected to http://secret-brushlands-1375.herokuapp.com/users/sign_up

Not sure what to make of this - the Facebook link is fine but my guess is the omniauth hash should not be nil and same of the session... ANy help appreciated.

Comment: Here is the logger output: Session: nil

 Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
 USer: #<User id: nil, email: "tstevens_21@earthlink.net", encrypted_password: "$K...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, nil, nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, provider: "facebook", uid: "141xxxxxx", name: "My name">
 Omniauth: nil
 Redirected to http://secret-brushlands-1375.herokuapp.com/users/sign_up

Comment: You are not getting any response from facebook at all. Try changing `request.env['omniauth.auth']` to `env['omniauth.auth']`. Make sure you are missing nothing from [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

Comment: Didn't work, but did redirect to user/sign_in instead of redirecting to Facebook.

Comment: Getting the same logs again? I think the only thing wrong there is the response you are getting from facebook. Rest of the things seems to be in place; so debugging in that area might be helpful :)

Comment: When I create a new user, the Facebook login works wonderfully as long as I am in the same session. As soon as I shutdown/restart the browser and try to Facebook login in again I always get redirected..

Comment: I think I have solved this by using :auth_type => 'reauthenticate' as described here: https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook. Thanks.